# Java HelloWorld commandline

Tags: java

I have problem running a basic helloworld application in Java form my command-line in widnows 7. I can run it in Java.

Here is my code(in NetBeans):

```
package helloworld;

public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Hello World!");

    }        
}
```

I have set **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin;** on my PATH variable in the Windows Environment.

When running :

```
javac HelloWorld.java
```

the HelloWorld.class is built successfully.

However in the next step when I run:

```
java HelloWorld
```

I get he following error:

**Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld**

Under my program source root directory I can see these two file:
 . HelloWorld.class
 . HelloWorld.java

What am I missing please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you need to do is as you have

```
package helloworld;
```

and you are trying to execute it from the commandline
do the following steps

First open the terminal or cmd and browse to the folder `helloworld`.
Example if your helloworld folder in in `f:/helloworld` open the terminal and browse upto `f:/`(don't go inside helloworld)

then compile the class as `javac helloworld/HelloWorld.java`

and try executing the class as `java helloworld.HelloWorld`

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked very well.

But couldn't I go inside the 'helloworld' folder and use: 

javac HelloWorld.java and java HelloWorld ?

What is helloworld relation to HelloWorld file here?

Comment: you need to use the fully qualified class name if you have the package defination in your class

Answer (score 2):

You should specify fully qualified class name. That is, you need to run it like that: `java helloworld.HelloWorld`.

Comment: Technically correct - I'd like to recommend using a task/dependency/build management system such as Gradle - this will make things much easier in the future.

Comment: Of course, then the `.class` file needs to be in `helloworld/HelloWorld.class`, not in the directory the `java` command is run from.

Comment: you should just use an ide

Comment: @vedi0boy The question was about running java application using command-line. Of course there are other ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

the class name was not fully qualified, try java `helloworld.HelloWorld`
the `.classfile` should not be in the directory the java command is run from.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot the helloworld package. So you have to enter `java helloworld.HelloWorld` to make it work. Next time please use a different package name than the java file, so there is no confusion. :)